# Open graph facebook trouble

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am developing a website for a store and I would like to publish the products on facebook. The problem is that the facebook open graph debugger preview is correct but viewing on facebook is completely wrong. can anybody help me?
here below I put the photos of the preview and the link on facebook[This is the facebook page layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK5CO.png)

Comment: We need to see the code you use, otherwise it will be hard to help you at all

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images